# Kable not including PNG in PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I'm trying to include a png in a kable column for a pdf. I use rmarkdown::render to knit the pdf. I'm also using tinytex and xelatex. The images work fine in html and a word doc, but I can't figure out why it won't work in a pdf.

The images render fine outside of the kable.

Here is my code:

````
    ---
    header-includes:
    - \usepackage{booktabs}
    - \usepackage{longtable}
    - \usepackage{array}
    - \usepackage{multirow}
    - \usepackage{wrapfig}
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \usepackage{colortbl}
    - \usepackage{pdflscape}
    - \usepackage{tabu}
    - \usepackage{threeparttable}
    - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
    - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
    - \usepackage{makecell}
    - \usepackage{xcolor}
    - \usepackage{fontspec}
    - \setmainfont{Calibri}
    output: 
      pdf_document:
        latex_engine: "xelatex"

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
    library(knitr)
    library(rmarkdown)
    library(kableExtra)
    up <- knitr::include_graphics("up-arrow.png", dpi = 100)
    down <- knitr::include_graphics("C:/Users/datimmer/Desktop/Notes/down-arrow.png")
    up
    down
    cat("![](",'C:/Users/datimmer/Desktop/Notes/up-arrow.png)',")")
    '![](C:/Users/datimmer/Desktop/Notes/up-arrow.png)'
    paste0('![test](C:/Users/datimmer/Desktop/Notes/up-arrow.png)')
    df <- data.frame(
      stock = c('Apple','Amazon','Microsoft','Tesla'),
      value = c(300,200,150,250),
      difference = c(50,-10,20,-15)
    )
    df$trend <- ifelse(df$difference >0,
                       sprintf('![](%s)', 'C:/Users/datimmer/Desktop/Notes/up-arrow.png'),
                       knitr::include_graphics("C:/Users/datimmer/Desktop/Notes/down-arrow.png")
                      )

    knitr::kable(df, 'latex')
````

Here is what my pdf looks like with this code, as you can see the pngs render fine outside of the kable.
[image]

And here is my session info:

```
> session_info()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1, RStudio 1.2.1335

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
  LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
  LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

Package version:
  askpass_1.1                assertthat_0.2.1           backports_1.1.4           
  base64enc_0.1.3            bayesDccGarch_2.1          BH_1.69.0-1               
  brew_1.0.6                 broom_0.5.2                callr_3.2.0               
  cellranger_1.1.0           cli_1.1.0                  clipr_0.6.0               
  clisymbols_1.2.0           coda_0.19.2                codetools_0.2-16          
  colorspace_1.4-1           commonmark_1.7             compiler_3.6.0            
  covr_3.3.1                 crayon_1.3.4               crosstalk_1.0.0           
  curl_3.3                   DBI_1.0.0                  dbplyr_1.4.0              
  desc_1.2.0                 devtools_2.2.1             digest_0.6.19             
  dplyr_0.8.1                DT_0.6.2                   ellipsis_0.3.0            
  evaluate_0.14              fansi_0.4.0                forcats_0.4.0             
  foreach_1.4.4              fs_1.3.1                            
            generics_0.0.2             ggplot2_3.1.1             
  gh_1.0.1                   git2r_0.25.2               glue_1.3.1                
  graphics_3.6.0             grDevices_3.6.0            grid_3.6.0                
  gtable_0.3.0               haven_2.1.0                highr_0.8                 
  hms_0.4.2                  htmltools_0.3.6            htmlwidgets_1.3           
  httpuv_1.5.1               httr_1.4.0                 ini_0.3.1                 
  iterators_1.0.10           jsonlite_1.6               kableExtra_1.1.0.9000     
  knitr_1.25                 labeling_0.3               later_0.8.0               
  lattice_0.20-38            lazyeval_0.2.2             lubridate_1.7.4           
  magrittr_1.5               markdown_0.9               MASS_7.3.51.4             
  Matrix_1.2.17              memoise_1.1.0              methods_3.6.0             
  mgcv_1.8.28                mime_0.7                   modelr_0.1.4              
  munsell_0.5.0              nlme_3.1-139               numDeriv_2016.8.1         
  openssl_1.3                PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.2 pillar_1.4.0              
  pkgbuild_1.0.3             pkgconfig_2.0.2            pkgload_1.0.2             
  plogr_0.2.0                plyr_1.8.4                 png_0.1-7                 
  pracma_2.2.5               praise_1.0.0               prettyunits_1.0.2         
  processx_3.3.1             progress_1.2.2             promises_1.0.1            
  ps_1.3.0                   purrr_0.3.2                quadprog_1.5-7            
  R6_2.4.0                   rcmdcheck_1.3.3            RColorBrewer_1.1.2        
  Rcpp_1.0.1                 RcppArmadillo_0.9.400.3.0  readr_1.3.1               
  readxl_1.3.1               rematch_1.0.1              remotes_2.1.0             
  reprex_0.3.0               reshape2_1.4.3             rex_1.1.2                 
  rlang_0.3.4                rmarkdown_1.12             RODBC_1.3-15              
  roxygen2_6.1.1             RPostgreSQL_0.6-2          rprojroot_1.3-2           
  rstudioapi_0.10            rversions_2.0.0            rvest_0.3.4               
  scales_1.0.0               selectr_0.4.1              sessioninfo_1.1.1         
  shiny_1.3.2                sourcetools_0.1.7          splines_3.6.0             
  stats_3.6.0                stringi_1.4.3              stringr_1.4.0             
  sys_3.2                    testthat_2.1.1             tibble_2.1.1              
  tidyr_0.8.3                tidyselect_0.2.5           tidyverse_1.2.1           
  tinytex_0.17               tools_3.6.0                usethis_1.5.0             
  utf8_1.1.4                 utils_3.6.0                vctrs_0.1.0               
  viridisLite_0.3.0          webshot_0.5.1.9001         whisker_0.3.2             
  withr_2.1.2                xfun_0.11                  XML_3.98-1.19             
  xml2_1.2.0                 xopen_1.0.0                xtable_1.8.4              
  xts_0.11-2                 yaml_2.2.0                 zeallot_0.1.0             
  zoo_1.8-5
```